# проверка строки на палиндром (слово проверяется, текст нет)

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Проверка слова палиндрома проходит, а строки ну никак, выдает False
пример палиндрома: А буду я у дуба

```
def palyndrom ():
    usr_string = input("enter string")

    urs_string = usr_string.replace(' ', '').replace(',', '').lower()

    reverce_str = usr_string[:: -1]


    if usr_string == reverce_str:
        print ("True")
    else :
        print("False")
palyndrom()
```

Comment: Вы сравниваете и реверсите `usr_string`, а надо сравнивать и реверсить `urs_string`, это две разные переменные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
def is_palyndrom(text: str) -> bool:
    text = text.lower().strip().replace(' ', '')
    return text == text[::-1]


text = 'А буду я у дуба'
print(is_palyndrom(text))
# True

usr_string = input("enter string")
print(is_palyndrom(usr_string))
```

Вместо удаления символов можно заново составить текст, оставив только те, что разрешены (из русского алфавита):

```
def is_palyndrom(text: str) -> bool:
    ru_lowercase = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
    text = ''.join(c for c in text.lower() if c in ru_lowercase)
    return text == text[::-1]
```

Или вариант через регулярки (тут все символы, что не входят в кириллицу, будут удалены):

```
import re

def is_palyndrom(text: str) -> bool:
    text = re.sub('[^а-яё]', '', text.lower())
    return text == text[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def palyndrom (usr_string):
    
    usr_string = re.sub(r'[\W ]','',usr_string).lower()
    
    if usr_string == usr_string[:: -1] :
        return "Палиндром"
 
    return "Не палиндром"
 
print(palyndrom(input("Введите текст для проверки: ")))
```